# What is the most memory efficient way of saving and building chunked images?

Tags: java

I have a server that accepts chunked images via JSON web service.
Currently it works fine but I'm worried as I'm constantly reading and writing files using the chunked data.

What is the most memory efficient way to implement this function if you are expecting some 10,000/min (10KB)images?

Currently, I just write the chunks directly to a file.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but is this 10.000 images|chunks|byte per minute?

Comment: Writing to a file is ok, assuming that the filesystem is fast enough and has lots of space. You want to allow parallel writing, but that just means writing to more files at once

Comment: I would recommend multithreading it for more efficiency. Other then that as long as the system can support it reasonably it should be fine.

Comment: Are there any indications that you are having problems with your current design? Have you performance tested your application?

Comment: @tucuxi assuming i would go with parallel writing. wouldn't there be a possible problem caused by the OS?

Comment: You are receiving data over a network; typical download speeds are slower than internal HDD writes, and senders may not be sending too fast. Multithreaded writing allows more throughput, limited of course by your max. write speed. Everything is limited by the OS and other factors (HW, ...) - space, open files, bandwidth, time. But this is generally a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about memory efficiency (as i understand) you already at the top. You are writing the chunked images to disk and then (hopefully) they will be gone from memory when the garbage collector cleans out the next time. Wether you could be more performing if you buffer the image chunks in memory should be tried out:

Imagine a class like this

```
public class InMemoryBuffer {
    Set<ChunkedImage> bufferedObjects;

    void buffer(ChunkedImage image) {
        bufferedObjects.add(image);
        if (sizeOfBufferExceedsThreshold())
        {
             // write buffered images to disk
        }
     }
}
```

I am not sure if i made my point clear. But to my opinion a best solution depends very much on your environment and your understanding of memory efficiency. In the above sample the to-be-filled-out-parts are the method that determines if the buffered images are to be written to disk and the write-to-disk part. At this point you could eventually profit from multi-threading.

Comment: I think I get your point...  I guess  I'll just have to look at the efficiency on how i subject everything to CG.